# Where can I find typescript typings for lodash/fp?

Tags: typescript, lodash

Where can I find typescript typings for lodash/fp? With lodash definitions form npm, I get an error when importing lodash/fp.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Creos cannot find module lodash/fp

Comment: I am having the same issue. It looks like it was supposed to be added? I am confused by this tooling ... https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/7896

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fp types now come with `@types/lodash`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash/fp

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the typings have been added to DefinitelyTyped under lodash/fp which can be found at their [repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash)

If you install the @types/lodash then the fp types should start to work as well

EDIT: I can confirm the FP types just work if you npm install the @types/lodash

I import them as `import map = require("lodash/fp/map")` so that webpack only packs that function in the build and the tests dont fail due to the `.default is not a function` error

Comment: It doesn't "just work" for me. So I import xx from lodash/fp/xx, and install @types/lodash, and I get all kinds of type errors. If I uninstall @types/lodash, my code works again. Am I doing something wrong?